# Android How to display 1 out of 54 card images in a ImageView

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out the best way to display 1 of 54 bitmaps in a `ImageView` .  I figured I could load in a bitmap from the assets.  But I can't figure out how to size it.  When it loads it from the `XML` file, it chooses 1 of 3 different bitmaps, each a different size.

I can't figure out how to determine what size bitmap to use.  I know how to get the width and height of a View, but not the whole screen.  Is there a way to get the screen resolution?

All so I know how to set the bitmap property of a `ImageView`, but I could not find anything for scaling.  Is there a way to scale it, or will I need a separate bitmap for different screen sizes?

This seems like it should be simple, but turning into something very complicated,

Is there a way to get the screen resolution?
Can I scale the bitmap a `ImageView` displays?
Is there a more easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bunch of questions here and I'm not clear on what you're actually trying to do, but the answers to the questions you ask last are:

> "Is there a way to get the screen resolution? "

Sure...

```
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()
```

> "Can I scale the bitmap a ImageView displays?"

An ImageView is just a container, so if you set its width and height and then load Bitmaps into it, they will scale to that Width and Height.

If you set its layout_width and layout_height to to `wrap_content` instead of a specific dimension then it will conform to whatever the dimensions of the image are (and grow and shrink as the different bitmaps are loaded).  If you're worried about different screens you need to put your images into different folders (with the same names), for different resolution devices, as per the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Bitmaps can be scaled any way you like manually as well using a Matrix. This is a little bit more complicated, so, I'll not venture to give examples until you clarify your answer and express an actual need for this.

Comment: Hi Thank you for answering my questions.  You stated that i can have the same images in different folder with different sizes.  I'm assuming you mean the drawable-large, drawable-med and drawable-small in the res folder.  I have the following code snippet to load images from the asset folder